# My XP computer no longer can connect to any network

Tags: windows-xp, workgroup

I used XP. I used to be able to access other computers on my network.

Now, if I go to network what I see is:

```
Mshome is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

The list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available
```

The computer workgroup name is indeed mshome. Moreover, an XP computer next to this computer can connect just fine. Also this computer can connect to internet. Hence, hardware is not an issue.

I searched around the net and couldn't find solutions.

IPConfig looks fine:
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.112
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

If I try to ping other computers, it won't work either.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>ping haryanto
Ping request could not find host haryanto. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>
```

The computer next to this computer can ping just fine.

I can, however ping, the IP number of those computer

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>ping 192.168.0.116

Pinging 192.168.0.116 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.0.116: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.116: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.116: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.116: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Other computers cannot ping 192.168.0.112 though.

Comment: Local firewall?

Comment: I typed \\fanny (fanny is the computer name). Then suddenly everything works again. It could be one of the other fix on the URL. However, this is what I will try next time this happen again.